# Can the notation for tempered logarithm function be made more clear?

Tags: notation, logarithms

My question is about **notation**, and whether I'm **justified** in saying it's confusing (and if I'm right, then what would be a better notation to avoid confusion?)

In "[Probabilistic Machine Learning: An Introduction](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html)", in section "10.4.2 Bi-tempered loss", the author defines the "**tempered version of the log function**" as:

[image]

And then writes:

> This is monotonically increasing and concave, and reduces to the standard (natural) logarithm when $t = 1$.

The author takes this definition from the paper titled "[Robust Bi-Tempered Logistic Loss Based on Bregman Divergences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03361)", whose authors make the similar statement for the same **tempered logarithm function**:

> The standard (natural) logarithm is recovered at the limit $t \to 1$.

My confusion **isn't** about the difference between the book's "$t = 1$" and paper's "$t \to 1$" (though I find the latter much easier to understand / 'more correct'), or "reduced versus recovered". My real confusion arises from the **notation** used on the left-hand side of the definition: I mean the usage of $t$ as subscript in $log_t(x)$, because, if I plot the **tempered logarithm function** as defined above for various values of the parameter $t$, I see the following:

For [$t = 0.4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%281%2F%281-t%29%29*%28x%5E%281-t%29%20-%201%29%20where%20t%3D0.4):

[image: tempered logarithm function at t = 0.4]

For [$t = 0.999999$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%281%2F%281-t%29%29*%28x%5E%281-t%29%20-%201%29%20where%20t%3D0.999999):

[image: tempered logarithm function at t = 0.999999]

And I can see that these indeed indicate that as "$t \to 1$", the defined function "converges" to the natural logarithm:

[$log(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20log%28x%29):

[image: plot of log(x)]

So, what's my problem? My problem is that I'm **used to perceiving** the **subscript** immediately following the $log$ as the **base** of the logarithm. In other words, when I see $log_t$, I take $t$ as the base of the logarithm, but obviously that's not the case here, because obviously, [$log_{0.999999}(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20log%20base%200.999999) is a very different function:

[image: plot of log base 0.999999]

Long story short, am I justified in being confused with respect to notation in this example? To me, this looks like authors being sort of "fast and loose" with the notation.

You might say "they clearly indicated that they defined the function as such, so you should not think about your previous experience with the notation used for indicating the base of logarithm function". To which I'd reply as: is there some kind of notation that would avoid this kind of confusion?

Comment: Not sure if these would be the seeds of answers, so you can confirm or clarify your question more, but it seems like you might be looking for one of 1. Logs with bases other than a fixed standard one (e.g. $e$, $10$) are extremely rare outside of secondary school, so there's no confusion for most because they just don't see log with a subscript often. Or 2. Sure, there are lots of notations that would avoid the conflict. For instance, just define $\log(t;x)$ when you write your paper/blog post/whatever.

Comment: @MarkS. your first point makes it clear for me, in the sense that I accept I'm not very justified in my confusion and based on the usage of logarithm notation and tradition in academic setting (obviously the case here, the book is a graduate level machine learning textbook, referring to a research paper) the notation in the book/paper is OK. Having said that, I must admit that your alternative notation would probably be less confusing for me. But that's just me. Thanks for your comment! :)